# Represent the search result by adding relevant description

Tags: search-engine

I'm developing simple search engine.If I search some thing using my search engine it will produce the list of urls which are relating with that search query.

I want to represent the search result by giving small,relevant description under each resulting url.(eg:- if we search something on google,you can see they will provide small description  with the each resulting link.)

Any idea..?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to store position of each word in a webpage while indexing.

your index should contain- word id , document id of the document containing this word, number of occurrence of the word in that document , all the positions where the word occurred.

[image: Indexer file structure]

For more info you can read the research paper by Google founders-
[The Anatomy of a Large-Scale Hypertextual Web Search Engine](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~backrub/google.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the meta content of that page and display it as a small description . Google also does this.

Comment: ::Yep ..I've already done.But the case is most of the web pages do not have meta content and if exist they are encrypted!

Is there any techniques to solve my prob..thank you!